# Which sensor should I use to detect a table tennis ball bounce in a table?

Tags: sensor

I am trying to create a table tennis statistics controller and I need to detect when a ball bounces on the table. My first idea was to use one piezo sensor in each side of the table, but the setup was not sensible enough. I also looked to use a camera, but it was more work than I first though. I wonder if there is a good sensor that could be used in this situation.

In the second phase, I would like find the approximate position where the ball has bounced. At first, I thought that I could do this with 3 piezo sensors and triangulation, but my tests were not successful.

Comment: Wow!  This sounds like an extraordinarily difficult project.  Are there any commercial solutions?  Is it similar to the technology used to judge in/out line calls in tennis?

Comment: Hi, there is something similar called [Stiga Sensor Score](http://www.amazon.com/STIGA-SensorScore-Automated-Tennis-Scoring/dp/B011UNAG40). I would like to create something similar, but my final objective is to prepare a bounce heatmap.

Comment: Cripes. There's at least [one](http://www2.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~sjc/BH_AV_QH2_SJC2.pdf) research paper and a [patent](http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US20110312450) on achieving this using audiovisual cues. Sounds *hard*. You might need a bigger computer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it might be a matter of acoustic impedance matching, that can be improved with a more efficient table-transducer mechanical coupling.
For example (I do not know details of your setup with the piezo transducer):
- rule out the air layer between the table and the piezo element, i.e., make a direct mechanical coupling between the table and the piezo element (you may glue the  latter to the table with a uniform layer of an elastic stuff); 
- or: arrange something working according to the principle of the stethoscope (take a look to wikipedia). Did you ever open a blood pressure meter (electronic, for personal use) to see it inside?

Until now, no more ideas available.

Answer (score 1):

If you had any form of audio sensors/microphones under the corners of the table, you might be able to pick up some parameters that were unambiguously a bounce (length of sound pulse, frequency components via [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), but probably not amplitude as a smash will be very different to clipping the net and dropping gently).  The reasons for attaching them to the table are: Keep them out of the way; enhance sensitivity to the bounce rather than ambient noise.

For location you'd need to triangulate using timing data.  The speed of sound in wood is ~10x that in air, so to get around 10cm accuracy you need 3µs timing precision.  Given the number of sensors and the speed requirements you're not going to do that on a Pi alone .  There are DSP ICs out there, some of which have development boards available but that could get expensive and difficult.

Position sensing is best done by camera, but perhaps an audio trigger would let you know when a bounce occured, as this would be hard to pick up from a single camera looking down from aboce, as would be required to give a nice position indicator.

Answer (score 0):

When you tried the camera, where was it positioned and how many fps is the camera? I'd try a side view to detect change of direction from falling (pre-bounce) to rising (post-bounce).

For the second phase, an overhead camera correlated with the sideview camera.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've found a couple of things for this problem, the [Adafruit 2340 Capacitive Touch HAT for Raspberry Pi MPR121](http://www.rapidonline.com/motion-sensing) looks like it might be useful, but with the requirement that you place a conductive surface over the surface of the table.

If you can do this that might be a good option.

Otherwise [this chap](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Ball-tracking/) has some ideas about how to track circular objects with a Raspberry pi - using table tennis as a specific example.

Not sure specifically how it would work out in practice as I haven't tried it, but I imagine that a couple of these systems in tandem would be able to triangulate.

Frankly though the Adafruit option seems best, as long as the conductive surface doesn't interfere too much with the bounce of the ball.

Answer (score 0):

Having no real experience with this, this is how I would start:

- Directional audio microphones by the net, four of them
- A contact microphone in each corner of the board, underneath it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYEtZk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(So Mic1-Mic4 are audio microphones, Mic5-Mic8 are contact microphones.)

Now - there's no audio input on the Pi, so you need to add this, and this setup uses quite a lot of microphones, so you'll need plenty of peripherals. There are many to choose from, I'll just give some examples:

- [Cirrus](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1761%20Cirrus)
- SYBA SD-CM-UAUD USB CM119

Once that is set up, you'll need to find a good way of picking out the sound of a bouncing ball. A good place to start could be looking at the project of a [raspberry pi powered bark-controlled dog door](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pi-rex-a-bark-activated-door-opener-for-dogs/).

Positioning should be achievable by checking difference in timing and/or amplitude between the different microphones.